# OneToMany deleting only one part of the relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

So, I have these classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbStudent")
public class Student {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
    private List<Report> reports;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbReport")
public class Report {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="student_fk", updatable=true, nullable=true)
    private Student student;
}
```

I would like to be able to delete one student but keep the report.

So, is there a way to update the student FK on report to null so I can delete the student with no problem?

I made a function in HQL that updates the FK to null everytime I try to delete a student but it doesnt seem to work.

Here it is:

```
public void deleteStudentReport(Student student){   
        String id = student.getId();
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("update Report r set r.student.id = null where r.student.id = :id");
        q.setParameter("id", id);       
}
```

EDIT:

I call the query when trying to remove the student:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "studentMB")
@ViewScoped
public class StudentMB {

    public void delete(){
        studentDao.deleteStudentReport(student);
        studentDao.delete(student);
   }
```

}

SOLUTION:

Thanks to Naros reply I ended up setting this method on the Student class:

```
@PreRemove
public void preRemove(){
    for(Report r : reports){
        d.setStudent(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're defining a query, but not executing it...

Comment: Just edited the post, I actually call the query function when deleting a Student.

Comment: No, you're not. To execute the query, you need to call query.executeUpdate(). And you're not calling it.

Comment: I told: "you're defining a **query**, but not **executing** it". You read that as "you didn't call the deleteStudentReport method". Don't blame me for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically just need a business function either on a repository/dao class or part of your service tier that takes a report instance and clears the student.

```
public void clearReportStudent(Report report) {
  if(report != null) {
    Student student = report.getStudent();
    if(student != null) {
      student.getReports().remove(report);      
      report.setStudent(null);
    }
  }
}
```

I generally prefer to put these type of helper methods on my domain models themselves and just invoke the operation from my service/business logic as needed.

```
public class Report {
  public void unlinkFromStudent() {
    if(this.student != null) {
      this.student.getReports().remove(this);
      this.student = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Dude, THANKS for your answer.

It actually did show what way should I lead.

I made a @PreRemove method on the Student that do exactly what I wanted, thanks again.